Spring Boot 3.4.1 migration, setFilterChains in WebSecurityConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found
migrating to Spring Boot 3.4.1 through this error
Description:

Parameter 0 of method setFilterChains in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - webSocketAuthorizationManagerPostProcessor: defined by method 'webSocketAuthorizationManagerPostProcessor' in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/socket/WebSocketObservationConfiguration.class]
    - objectPostProcessor: defined by method 'objectPostProcessor' in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/configuration/ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration.class]

This may be due to missing parameter name information

There is a recommendation
Ensure that your compiler is configured to use the '-parameters' flag.
You may need to update both your build tool settings as well as your IDE.
(See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention)

I've configured ma Kotlin settings following the recommendation in the Spring Framework 6.1 migration guide
build.gradle.kts
tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}

The error is still there
Any idea?

Having done many of these migrations, I always look in their source code when faced with a problem. Set breakpoints, and walk through the start up. The parameter name warning is unlikely to be related to the duplicate bean error.

Could you please show us your WebSecurityConfiguration class?

Related to SEC#16299
In fact, this is caused by Spring. I have reported this issue
